# how to make a batch file close automatically

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, telnet, netcat

I have a `.bat` file which its content is like this:

```
@echo off
nc x.x.x.x 23 < commands.txt
exit
```

in which `nc` is a .exe file in the same directory `nc.exe` known as NetCat.
The `commands.txt` file has some telnet commands which are sent to `x.x.x.x` ip address, which is like this:

```
Username
Password
systemlog show
a command
exit
```

when I call that `.bat` file it does it work but it does not close the cmd window it has opened. Seems the exit commands in both files does not do any work to close the window.
I've also tried using `start` command in batch file, but it does not work. (even Ive quoted `nc x.x.x.x 23 < commands.txt` after start command, no way.)
Is there any way to close the cmd window opened by batch file?
There is a way but that involves converting batch file to exe which is not a good work (security).

Comment: You could try to use .cmd file instead of .bat file.  Are you sure that the exit command is executed? I would think it could be that the nc.exe call somehow blocks the rest of the batch processing. Could you try to verify that there is any command executet after the nc? E.G you could do a "Ping localhost > C:\Test\Test.txt" and check if the file is created.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic yeah you are right, it did not work (i.e. the file is not created). Also I removed the exit command from `commands.txt` file and retested it, did not help. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to specify a timeout for netcat, e.g.

```
 nc -w 10 x.x.x.x 23 < commands.txt
```

Netcat will quit after 10 seconds of inactivity.